# Select multiple aggregation result from the same subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions, lateral

I find myself doing statistics like this more and more often - for every record in tbl1, use it as condition to scan tbl2 and do aggregation on tbl2, return the aggregated results. This is easy with sub-query.

But I need to do multiple aggregation in one pass in the same subquery instead of scanning multiple times.

For example, here is some sample data for analysis:

```
SELECT  to_timestamp((random()*999999)) evt_ts, 
    evt_id  
    INTO temp.test_so_44410354
FROM
    (
        SELECT *, (random()*2000)::int AS idx
            FROM generate_series( 1, 1000) AS evt_id
            ORDER BY idx 
    ) AS t

evt_ts              |evt_id |
--------------------|-------|
1970-01-01 08:13:15 |109    |
1970-01-01 08:17:22 |762    |
1970-01-01 08:19:28 |630    |
1970-01-01 08:29:34 |429    |
1970-01-01 08:48:28 |70     |
```

To see how events distribute over an given time frame, 
current approach & query plan & desired output :

```
With wcal AS (
    SELECT ts, ts::date as dt 
    FROM generate_series( '1970-01-01 0:0:0', '1970-01-12 0:0:0', INTERVAL '1 day' ) AS ts
)
SELECT ts, dt
,(
    SELECT count(evt_ts) 
    FROM temp.test_so_44410354 as el
    WHERE ( el.evt_ts < wcal.ts AND el.evt_ts > wcal.ts - INTERVAL '1 day'  )
) as ecnt
,(
    SELECT sum(evt_id) -- should be array_agg, sum is locate to the difference in the results.
    FROM temp.test_so_44410354 as el
    WHERE ( el.evt_ts < wcal.ts AND el.evt_ts > wcal.ts - INTERVAL '1 day'  )
) as eids
FROM wcal

QUERY PLAN                                                                                          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=12.50..21314.08 rows=1000 width=28)                                         |
  CTE wcal                                                                                          |
    ->  Function Scan on generate_series ts  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=12)                  |
  SubPlan 2                                                                                         |
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=10.63..10.64 rows=1 width=8)                                               |
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_so_44410354 el  (cost=4.33..10.62 rows=5 width=8)            |
                Recheck Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal.ts - '1 day'::interval)))     |
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_so_44410354_idx  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=5 width=0)     |
                      Index Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal.ts - '1 day'::interval))) |
  SubPlan 3                                                                                         |
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=10.63..10.64 rows=1 width=8)                                               |
    ...

ts                  |dt         |ecnt |eids  |
--------------------|-----------|-----|------|
1970-01-01 00:00:00 |1970-01-01 |0    |      |
1970-01-02 00:00:00 |1970-01-02 |68   |36156 |
1970-01-03 00:00:00 |1970-01-03 |85   |42103 |
1970-01-04 00:00:00 |1970-01-04 |94   |47092 |
1970-01-05 00:00:00 |1970-01-05 |74   |36276 |
....
```

There are 2 subplans, it *seems* pg will have to scan table `evt_log` twice to do the same aggregation twice. I'd would like avoid this. since the aggregation conditions are exactly the same and it maybe be much faster if it can do many statistical aggregation in one pass. Logs can grow very big, the processing will take quite some time.

Feedback on proposed solution I 
nested `join` is not working as expected:

```
With wcal AS (
SELECT ts, ts::date as dt 
FROM generate_series( '1970-01-01 0:0:0', '1970-01-12 0:0:0', INTERVAL '1 day' ) AS ts
)
, ag AS (
    SELECT 
        count(evt_ts) AS ecnt
      , sum(evt_id) AS eids
    FROM temp.test_so_44410354 as el
    JOIN wcal ON ( el.evt_ts < wcal.ts AND el.evt_ts > wcal.ts - INTERVAL '1 day'  )
)
SELECT ts, dt, ag.ecnt, eids
FROM wcal
JOIN ag ON true

QUERY PLAN                                                                                                            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Nested Loop  (cost=4239.57..4269.59 rows=1000 width=28)                                                               |
  CTE wcal                                                                                                            |
    ->  Function Scan on generate_series ts  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=12)                                    |
  CTE ag                                                                                                              |
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=4227.06..4227.07 rows=1 width=16)                                                            |
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..3671.50 rows=111111 width=12)                                                  |
                ->  CTE Scan on wcal wcal_1  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=8)                                     |
                ->  Index Scan using test_so_44410354_idx on test_so_44410354 el  (cost=0.28..2.54 rows=111 width=12) |
                      Index Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal_1.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal_1.ts - '1 day'::interval)))               |
  ->  CTE Scan on ag  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=16)                                                               |
  ->  CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=12)                                                         |

ts                  |dt         |ecnt |eids   |
--------------------|-----------|-----|-------|
1970-01-01 00:00:00 |1970-01-01 |920  |464436 |
1970-01-04 00:00:00 |1970-01-04 |920  |464436 |
1970-01-05 00:00:00 |1970-01-05 |920  |464436 |
1970-01-06 00:00:00 |1970-01-06 |920  |464436 |
1970-01-07 00:00:00 |1970-01-07 |920  |464436 |
....
```

Feedack on proposed solution II:
The writing are different but the query plan are basically the same with 2 sub plan.

```
DROP TYPE temp.my_agg ;
CREATE TYPE temp.my_agg AS ( ecnt int, eids int );
EXPLAIN
With wcal AS (
    SELECT ts, ts::date as dt 
    FROM generate_series( '1970-01-01 0:0:0', '1970-01-12 0:0:0', INTERVAL '1 day' ) AS ts
)
SELECT ts, dt
,(
    SELECT (count(evt_ts),sum(evt_id))::temp.my_agg
    FROM temp.test_so_44410354 as el
    WHERE ( el.evt_ts < wcal.ts AND el.evt_ts > wcal.ts - INTERVAL '1 day'  )
).*
FROM wcal

QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=12.50..21349.08 rows=1000 width=20) (actual time=0.182..3.518 rows=12 loops=1)                                      |
  CTE wcal                                                                                                                                  |
    ->  Function Scan on generate_series ts  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.057..0.083 rows=12 loops=1)               |
  SubPlan 2                                                                                                                                 |
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=10.64..10.66 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.140..0.140 rows=1 loops=12)                                           |
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_so_44410354 el  (cost=4.33..10.62 rows=5 width=12) (actual time=0.049..0.083 rows=77 loops=12)       |
                Recheck Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal.ts - '1 day'::interval)))                                             |
                Heap Blocks: exact=66                                                                                                       |
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_so_44410354_idx  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=77 loops=12) |
                      Index Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal.ts - '1 day'::interval)))                                         |
  SubPlan 3                                                                                                                                 |
    ...
Planning time: 0.548 ms                                                                                                                     |
Execution time: 3.748 ms                                                                                                                    |
```

For proposed solution II, if the aggregation is returned as record, the query plan will look like below:
Which roughly doubled the speed c.f. previous query. (but record type element is not desired as final result.)

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=12.50..10690.79 rows=1000 width=44) (actual time=0.147..1.979 rows=12 loops=1)                                      |
  CTE wcal                                                                                                                                  |
    ->  Function Scan on generate_series ts  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.057..0.082 rows=12 loops=1)               |
  SubPlan 2                                                                                                                                 |
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=10.64..10.66 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.151..0.151 rows=1 loops=12)                                           |
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_so_44410354 el  (cost=4.33..10.62 rows=5 width=12) (actual time=0.054..0.089 rows=77 loops=12)       |
                Recheck Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal.ts - '1 day'::interval)))                                             |
                Heap Blocks: exact=66                                                                                                       |
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_so_44410354_idx  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=77 loops=12) |
                      Index Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal.ts - '1 day'::interval)))                                         |
Planning time: 0.381 ms                                                                                                                     |
Execution time: 2.147 ms                                                                                                                    |
```

The `LATERAL` join solution works just as expected. Thanks.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
With wcal AS (
    SELECT ts, ts::date as dt 
    FROM generate_series( '1970-01-01 0:0:0', '1970-01-12 0:0:0', INTERVAL '1 day' ) AS ts
)
SELECT ts, dt, p.*
FROM wcal
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT count(evt_ts), sum(evt_id)
        FROM temp.test_so_44410354 as el
        WHERE ( el.evt_ts < wcal.ts AND el.evt_ts > wcal.ts - INTERVAL '1 day'  )
    ) p

QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Nested Loop  (cost=23.15..10705.79 rows=1000 width=28) (actual time=0.130..1.611 rows=12 loops=1)                                         |
  CTE wcal                                                                                                                                |
    ->  Function Scan on generate_series ts  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.054..0.075 rows=12 loops=1)             |
  ->  CTE Scan on wcal  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=0.061..0.099 rows=12 loops=1)                                  |
  ->  Aggregate  (cost=10.64..10.65 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.123..0.123 rows=1 loops=12)                                           |
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_so_44410354 el  (cost=4.33..10.62 rows=5 width=12) (actual time=0.044..0.074 rows=77 loops=12)       |
              Recheck Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal.ts - '1 day'::interval)))                                             |
              Heap Blocks: exact=66                                                                                                       |
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_so_44410354_idx  (cost=0.00..4.33 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.033..0.033 rows=77 loops=12) |
                    Index Cond: ((evt_ts < wcal.ts) AND (evt_ts > (wcal.ts - '1 day'::interval)))                                         |
Planning time: 0.399 ms                                                                                                                   |
Execution time: 1.778 ms                                                                                                                  |

ts                  |dt         |count |sum   |
--------------------|-----------|------|------|
1970-01-01 00:00:00 |1970-01-01 |0     |      |
1970-01-02 00:00:00 |1970-01-02 |68    |36156 |
1970-01-03 00:00:00 |1970-01-03 |85    |42103 |
1970-01-04 00:00:00 |1970-01-04 |94    |47092 |
1970-01-05 00:00:00 |1970-01-05 |74    |36276 |
1970-01-06 00:00:00 |1970-01-06 |96    |43797 |
```

Comment: did you forget  to include the question?

Comment: Was in a hurry, I edited it hopefully it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
With wcal AS (
    SELECT ts, ts::date as dt, 
        extract( week from ts) as wk, 
        extract( month from ts ) as mo,
        extract( quater from ts ) as qtr,
    FROM generate_series( t1, t2, tspan )
)
SELECT ts, dt, wk, mo, qtr, ecnt, eids
from
  wcal cross join lateral (
    SELECT count(evt_ts) as ecnt, array_agg(evt_id) as eids
    FROM ev_log as el
    WHERE (el.ts < wcal.ts AND el.ts < wcal.ts - tspan)) as el;
```

`<table> cross join lateral (<query>)` is a synonym to `<table>, lateral (<query>)`.

Answer (score 2):

smth like?

```
With wcal AS (
    SELECT ts, ts::date as dt, 
        extract( week from ts) as wk, 
        extract( month from ts ) as mo,
        extract( quater from ts ) as qtr,
    FROM generate_series( t1, t2, tspan )
)
, ag as (
    SELECT count(evt_ts) ecnt,  array_aggr(evt_id) eids
    FROM ev_log as el
    JOIN wcal on (el.ts < wcal.ts AND el.ts < wcal.ts - tspan)
)
SELECT ts, dt, wk, mo, qtr, ecnt, eids
FROM wcal 
JOIN ag on true
```

I'm not sure about the join conditions - you need to put the whole query to the OP to be able to guess

**updated**

according to Abelisto notices - thank you

Comment: Is it really possible to use one CTE in the another one?

Comment: at least in 9.6. let me check earlier versions - you are too good to ask for no reason

Comment: `with a(x) as (values(1)), b(y) as (select * from generate_series(1,a.x)) select * from b;` - `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"` (9.5 version)

Comment: ah - I see what you mean - I dont use from wcal in ag alias - true - should fail

Comment: should be like ```with a as (select 1 i)
, b as (select 1 e from a where a.i = 1)
select * from b;
 e
---
 1
(1 row)
```

Comment: added `JOIN wcal on true` to `ag` CTE - now should work. Thank you

Comment: `JOIN wcal on (el.ts < wcal.ts AND el.ts < wcal.ts - tspan)` is better a bit I think :o)

Answer (score 1):

It is tricky a bit but:

```
create type t_my_aggs as (ecnt bigint, eids bigint[]);

With wcal AS (
    SELECT ts, ts::date as dt, 
        extract( week from ts) as wk, 
        extract( month from ts ) as mo,
        extract( quater from ts ) as qtr,
    FROM generate_series( t1, t2, tspan )
)
SELECT ts, dt, wk, mo, qtr
,(
    SELECT row(count(evt_ts), array_agg(evt_id))::t_my_aggs 
    FROM ev_log as el
    WHERE ( el.ts < wcal.ts AND el.ts < wcal.ts - tspan )
).* from wcal;
```

Comment: @Ben Added yet another solution

Comment: Could you separate the lateral version to new answer. I'd like to accept it. Honestly I never paid attention to `lateral`, seldom seen people use it. Now it looks just engineered to cases like mine. Thanks.